# How was the range of a 32 bit register defined?

Tags: range, bit

I have a doubt..range of a 32 bit register is 2^32 ..is it because a bit can store 2 values if yes please could you justify it..it's really confusing..

Comment: 1 bit register can hold, 1 or 0, 2^1.  2 bits can be 00, 01, 10, 11, 2^2 ... keep going from there to convince yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 2 bit. The possible different binary values you could create., with 2 bit is `00, 01,10, and 11` hence 2^2 = 4. Hence, for decimal you could store 0,1,2,3 (4 vlaues) with 2 bits.

Similar case applies to 32 bits.